# Confusion on passing variables between controller and service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just started learning AngularJS. I know this has been asked multiple times, but I am just not getting it. I've been at this for hours now, between reading example code here and fiddling about in my IDE.

I have the following code which is supposed to retrieve a section key for an item and then pass that key to a service which consumes an API to provide a response which populates the categories based on that key. This happens when a section table row is clicked.

The HTML

```
<div ng-controller="menuController">
    <h1>AngularTest</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
         <tbody>
            <tr ng-click="getSectionID($event)" ng-repeat-start="section in navSectionList" data-id="{{section.id}}">                    
                    <td>{{section.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{section.name}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat-end="categories in navGetCategories">
                <td>{{categories.id}}</td>
                <td>{{categories.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

navController.js

```
var navApp = angular.module('navApp', ['ngResource']);

navApp.controller('menuController', ['$scope', 'navSectionList', 'navGetCategories',
    function ($scope, navSectionList, navGetCategories) {
        $scope.navSectionList = navSectionList.query();
        $scope.getSectionID = function (event) {

            var sectionID = event.currentTarget.attributes["data-id"].value;
            $scope.sectionID = sectionID;
            //console.log($scope.sectionID);

            $scope.navGetCategories = navGetCategories.query(sectionID);
        };   
    }
]);
```

navService.js

```
navApp.factory('navSectionList', [
    '$resource', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('/api/navigation/section/list', {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
        });
    }
]);

navApp.factory('navGetCategories', [
    '$resource', function ($resource) {

        return $resource('/api/navigation/category/' + sectionID, {}, {
            query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }        
        });
    }
]);
```

How do I get the value from the navController to the navService so that it can use that value to query the API? I feel like this should be something incredibly simple and basic but I'm either lacking sleep or lacking smarts at the moment. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to change your services to something like this:

```
navApp.factory('navGetCategories', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    var service = {
        getResource: function(sectionID) {
            return $resource('/api/navigation/category/' + sectionID, {}, {
                query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }        
            });
        }
    }
    return service;
}]);
```

And then to use it will be something like this:

```
$scope.navGetCategories = navGetCategories
    .getResource(sectionID)
    .query();
```

Comment: I get the following error when I try this code: ReferenceError: sectionId is not defined

Comment: Oh wait that seems like a typo.

Comment: My example seems to have been miscapitalized :)

Comment: Hey this actually works! Thank you. Would it be terrible of me to ask you to explain how this works?

Comment: So, when you use `.factory`, whatever you return will be the thing that your controllers can interact with. You were directly returning a resource object. That's certainly legal code, but in your case, you don't know how to make that resource object until you have the id, so what you really want is a function that takes an id and then returns a resource object. I named that function `getResource`. It's common for services to have many functions on them, so i then wrapped it into an object (named `service`), so that if you later decide you want more functions, they're easy to add to that object

Comment: In fact, that's a step you could do to improve things. Instead of having two factories (`navSectionList` and `navGetCategories`), you could combine them into one; perhaps named `navData`. It would then have a `getSectionList` function, and a `getCategories` function. So that way, all your nav data can be found in one service.

Comment: I see. Now I'm getting any errors here, but what happened to the response though? Where did it go?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154493/discussion-between-nicholas-tower-and-i-r-r).

Answer (score 2):

```
navApp.factory('navGetCategories', [
    '$resource', function ($resource) {

        return {
            getResouce:getResouce
        }
        function  getResouce(sectionID)  {
            return $resource('/api/navigation/category/' + sectionID, {}, {
                query: { method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: true }
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

Then call it like

```
navGetCategories.getResource(sectionID).query();
```

Comment: This resulted in nothing happening, no error message, no change in the html output.

Comment: navGetCategories.getResource(sectionID).query() should work.